# Add number format as currency in animating number(10,000)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The amount is animating from start value to end value but i want to animate this amount number into formatted way. Let suppose number start animating from 1000 to 10000 then it should be formatted as 10,000

```js
function myCalculator() {
  $(".container2").show();
  var start = 1000;
  var end = 10000;
  var duration = 2000;
  animateValue("value", start, end, duration).toLocaleString();
}

function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  var range = end - start;
  var current = start;
  var increment = end > start ? 10 : -10;
  var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    current += increment;
    obj.innerHTML = current;
    if (current == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="myCalculator();">Click Here to See Animation</button>

<div class="container2" style="display:none;">
  Animating Amount $ <span id="value"></span>
</div>
```

I tried a lot but not found any luck. can anyone help me to fixed it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rory I dont know what to do. Can you please fix it ?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `toLocaleString()` in the wrong place. You need to call it on the `current` variable within the `animateValue` function, not on the (non-existant) result of that function. Try this:

```js
function myCalculator() {
  $(".container2").show();
  var start = 1000;
  var end = 10000;
  var duration = 2000;
  animateValue("value", start, end, duration); // remove .toLocaleString()
}

function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  var range = end - start;
  var current = start;
  var increment = end > start ? 10 : -10;
  var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    current += increment;
    obj.innerHTML = current.toLocaleString(); // add .toLocaleString() here
    if (current == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="myCalculator();">Click Here to See Animation</button>

<div class="container2" style="display:none;">
  Animating Amount $ <span id="value"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Comment: okk @Rory I will accept it, And I am also expecting to vote up for my question.

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat(current).toLocaleString('en-US');` Do the trick

```js
function myCalculator() {
  $(".container2").show();
  var start = 1000;
  var end = 10000;
  var duration = 2000;
  animateValue("value", start, end, duration);
}

function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  var range = end - start;
  var current = start;
  var increment = end > start ? 10 : -10;
  var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    current += increment;
    obj.innerHTML = parseFloat(current).toLocaleString('en-US');
    if (current == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="myCalculator();">Click Here to See Animation</button>

<div class="container2" style="display:none;">
  Animating Amount $ <span id="value"></span>
</div>
```